# Java FX: comparing the coordinates of different objects in a pane to the coordinates of the mouse when right clicked

Tags: java, javafx

I don't know how to compare all of the x and y of the circle objects on pane to those of the mouse. The problem Im working on asks me to to set it so the secondary click of the mouse removes a point when it is placed on it, I figure I can do this by comparing all of the distances of the circles coordinates and the mouse coordinates (using distance formula) to the radi of the circles. If one of the distances is less than the radi I would remove that circle. The problem is that I dont know how to call all of the points on the pane so I can compare them. This is the code I have so far to give you a better understanding of how the points are  set up.

```
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Homework6 extends Application {

@Override // Override the start method in the Application class
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    // Create a pane and set its properties
    Pane pane = new Pane();
    //Circle circle1 = new Circle(7);
    Circle[] circles = new Circle[0];


    pane.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
        switch (e.getButton()) {

            case PRIMARY:
                Circle circle1 = new Circle(7);
                circle1.setCenterX(e.getX());
                circle1.setCenterY(e.getY());
                pane.getChildren().add(circle1);
                circle1.setFill(Color.WHITE);
                circle1.setStroke(Color.BLACK);


            case SECONDARY:



        }
    });

    // Create a scene and place the pane in the stage
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
    primaryStage.setTitle("KeyEventDemo"); // Set the stage title
    primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
    primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage

    pane.requestFocus(); // text is focused to receive key input
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

No need to do any computations! Method `evt.getTarget()` should already return the circle that has been clicked.

Have a look at [Oracle's JavaFX tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/processing.htm#CEGJAAFD) to learn how to handle event.

Comment: I've never used that before and am not sure how it works

Comment: What are you unsure about? Just call getTarget on the event to get the circle under the mouse pointer!

Comment: If you just register a listener with the `Circle` for deleting it, instead of using the listener registered with the `pane`, you don't even need to call `getTarget()`.